# Invalid Operation Exception - "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'TextBox1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

> "If necessity is the mother of
>   invention, I'd like to kill the guy
>   who invented this."
>
> -Jimmy Buffet

I don't care if 100 people with a million reputation jump down my throat for saying this, but who ever thought of throwing this exception deserves a fate worse than death.

I have **QUITE LITERALLY** copied and pasted code from one project to another to populate standard data into a small set of text boxes.  In one application, the data is displayed perfectly.  The new one I'm working on now, throws this exception of course.

So here is my question - why would one throw it and the other not if the code is the same?  Is there a setting in the project settings?  Is there a property in the text box that prevents this?

I don't recall setting anything in the project to ignore this exception, but the code is **EXACTLY THE SAME**.

Comment: You're going to need to show some code.

Comment: You pasted it into a non-UI thread.

Comment: Probably should learn about threads and asynchronous programming before getting on your high horse and declaring something stupid.

Comment: Why don't you learn something about who you're talking to before blurting out insults?  I just don't feel that creating a delegate, checking for invoke required, invoking a multi-argument delegate, and then seeing the results is an efficient replacement for something that effectively is lock(mylock){string1=string2;}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

STAThread attribute set on the thread creating the controls?

Is the populating code called in the UI thread or not? Noone cares whether you did copy the code properly - if the call is on the wrong thread to start with.

Comment: Well, it does not have to be set. It should be on the Main method, and other wise set the any other thread's appartement to STA: thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to repeat the error message, but you are trying to modify a control from a thread different than th thread that control was created on.

Take a look at [InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=VS.90).aspx) and [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=VS.90).aspx).